# when reading in GO VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Error when using any input function. I didn't find anything similar in the settings

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var i = 2
    fmt.Println("Write your name:")
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &i)
    fmt.Print(&i)
}
```

Error when using any input function.I didn't find anything similar in the settings

[image]

Comment: Unable to process `evaluate`: debuggee is running

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged with Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code, they are not the same thing.

Comment: VSCode, I clicked by mistake instead of "VSC Debugger"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.